# Exclude specific restful URLs from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, query-string

I have a bunch of line items in my report. For example:

```
page/1
page/2
page/1/session/ABCDEFGHIJ
page/2/session/MNBVCFRTY
```

I've read articles on how to ignore querystring parameters but how would I ignore the session key and it's value in a restful environment? It will always be at the end of the URL

I tried doing a search-and-replace filter as follows:

```
Search: /session/(.*)
Replace: /
```

When verifying it, it works but the reports still show the session data

Comment: You need to implement logic when your analytics tag should not be firing. If you are using google tag manager you can trigger this on specific url's.. so they prevent the tracking code to register the hit.

Comment: I still want them to register the page - I don't want to ignore them - but to search/replace that part of the session. When I verify the rules, the results are fine but then when applied in the report.

Comment: Alright, I see what you mean. Take a look at this solution: https://makandracards.com/makandra/8195-google-analytics-change-the-tracked-url-path   I think that would push you in the right direction.